# Search Multiple Database Columns with a Single Textbox Using dataGridView

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a single textbox to search multiple
columns in a database. The following code works for one
single column.

```
private void tboxSearchRID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "RID1 LIKE '%" + tboxSearchRID.Text + "%'" ;
}
```

This code works fine with just the single Database column RID1. 
Is there a way that I can include RID2, RID3, RID4 into the same
search?
Here is a snapshot of my Search Form
[My Search Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upbwk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are talking about an ADO.NET DataView right?

You can use a filter that applies to multiply columns `OR` in the SQL:

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format(
  "RID1 LIKE '%{0}%' OR RID2 LIKE '%{0}%' OR RID3 LIKE '%{0}%' OR RID4 LIKE '%{0}%'", tboxSearchRID.Text
);
```

Comment: And a Home run for you, my friend. How fortunate to get the perfect answer on the first try.  I'm only a hobby programmer with (believe it or not) about 2 - 3 weeks experience and absolutely no training. So, my questions may be simple, but a real PITA to solve on my own. 
Thank you so much